# android app authentication

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication

I am kinda new to programming.
I ask the courtesy of someone who understands the subject can give a direction.

I would like to do an application on android that will have at 1st screen a login+pass screen.
The user will have to set username+password and then hit a button, so it will verify and if it is right he will enter the application.
For example: skype for android do it.

After my searches I found that to do it, a way is create a php+mysql+json+session server to authenticate.

So I thought. I will have to do a code on android that will send user+pass to the php page then it will look into the database and will return for example 1 for success and 0 for unsucess.
If sucessfull it will have to save a information on the phone to identificate the user because on the second screen he will have an option that when he click it it will look into the mysql database and return for example the names listed in this database.

At internet have a lot of information but I am confused.
I would like to know what I have to look for to learn how to do the code at the android app login screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First learn how to create hello world apps in android as described [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html).
- Then learn how to make layouts using XML as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).
- Then learn how to communicate with your server as explained [here](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/).

Good luck.